# Jenkins: LDAP username/email lookup

Tags: active-directory, ldap, svn, jenkins

My **Jenkins LDAP configuration** works fine for the user login and user details. The user *John Doe* can login with his username *jdoe* and his password. His initial user information (*user/jdoe/configure*) are correct:

> Your name: John Doe (HR)
>   E-mail address: john.doe@company.com

But when he commits his changes to SVN and his modification triggers a new build he doesn't get the email. The error message from the build output:

> Failed to send e-mail to com\jdoe because no e-mail address is known, and no default e-mail domain is configured

It clear to me that Jenkins cannot resolve *com\jdoe* to the Jenkins User Id *jdoe*. But how can I change my configuration that the Jenkins User Id is *com\jdoe*? Or is there a better solution?

The LDAP configuration:

> User search filter: sAMAccountName={0}
>   Display Name LDAP attribute: displayName
>   Email Address LDAP attribute: mail
>   Disable Ldap Email Resolver: deactivated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by modifying the Apache configuration and changing the username from domain\username to username only.

**httpd-svn.conf**

```
AuthType SSPI
SSPIAuth On
SSPIAuthoritative Off
SSPIDomain mydomain
SSPIOfferBasic On
SSPIUsernameCase lower

#remove the domain from the username
SSPIOmitDomain On
```